# Как программно авторизоваться на Яндекс?

Tags: авторизация, яндекс-фотки

**tl;dr**

Как программно авторизоваться на **Яндекс.Фотках**, и получить куки (может что-то еще) для программного выполнения запроса по адресу http://fotki.yandex.ru/internal/get-my-albums.xml ?

## Предыстория

Необходимо быстро получать коллекцию альбомов на сервисе Яндекс.Фотки для формирования из них уже локального кэша. Но, так как на сервисе стоит жесткое ограничение на 100 записей на одну страницу коллекции, "в лоб" эта операция занимает очень много времени - альбомов уже больше 10 000.

Ниже приведен текст моего предыдущего вопроса на Тостере:

---

**Как быстро получить иерархию альбомов на Яндекс.Фотках?**

Если следовать официальной документации, то следует строить иерархию следующим образом:

- Постранично прочитать всю коллекцию альбомов (100 штук на страницу
  максимум)
- Просмотреть каждый Entry-элемент
- Выстроить иерархию по
  ссылкам на родительские альбомы

Однако, на больших объемах это работает крайне медленно. 
При ~8000 альбомов требуется ~80 сетевых запросов.

Распараллелить эти запросы не удается, так как заранее неизвестны все ID (и даты обновления) альбомов. Поэтому приходится в прямом смысле загружать "постранично" - в каждой странице есть ссылка на следующую страницу.

В то же время на Яндекс.Фотках есть вот такие ссылки (нужно авторизоваться)

- fotki.yandex.ru/actions/ajax-albums-list.xml?author=USERNAME
- fotki.yandex.ru/internal/get-my-albums.xml

которые отдают сформированный список очень быстро (да, он неполный, но тут это не важно).

Вопрос: куда копать для ускорения загрузки дерева?

Может быть есть какая-нибудь незадокументированная возможность получить дерево по API?
Если нет, то как программно авторизоваться на Яндекс.Фотках (OAuth токен не работает), чтобы слать запросы по этому урлу - fotki.yandex.ru/internal/get-my-albums.xml ?

---

## Наши дни

Как я ни пытался сформировать список страниц коллекции стандартными средствами - ничего не получается. Поддержка Яндекса не отвечает.

Поэтому я сейчас вижу только один выход - программно авторизоваться на Яндекс (Яндекс.Паспорт, наверное) и послать запросто по этому урлу - fotki.yandex.ru/internal/get-my-albums.xml.

Однако у меня не получается этого сделать - OAuth авторизация не работает, а как авторизоваться по логину-паролю Яндекс.Паспотра я не понимаю.

**Вопрос**: Как программно авторизоваться на **Яндекс.Фотках**, и получить куки (может что-то еще) для программного выполнения запроса по адресу http://fotki.yandex.ru/internal/get-my-albums.xml